# How do I use same decorators on more than one function in python?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-testing

I am testing in django and using decorator mock.patch.object() for mocking object methods. I want to use same decorators in another funtion of that class. For this I moved the decorators from function to class. This solved my problem, but now I want to add another test funtion, which should not mock those functions.

```
@mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'class_fun_2')
@mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'class_fun_1')
class TestClass(testcases.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
    # contains my setup that I want to use in all functions for this test class

    def test_function_1(self, mocked_class_fun_1, mocked_class_fun_2):
    # I want to use those mocked functions here

    def test_function_2(self, mocked_class_fun_1, mocked_class_fun_2):
    # I want to use those mocked functions here too

    def test_function_3(self):
    # I do not want to use those mocked functions here
```

If I do this, it is throwing an error:

```
TypeError: test_function_3() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

So what should I do, so that I can use the setUp in all functions and mocked funtions in only two funtions?

PS: I have shown only 2 mocked funtions, but in reality I am mocking 8 functions, so repetition of mock.patch might not be a good idea.

Comment: Could you create a parent test class (i.e. `TestClassParent`, then inherit from that class into two subclasses - one that you decorate and one that you don't? That will allow you to share the setUp code between both classes, and only mock those that are present in one of the classes with the class decorator.

Comment: It sounds like test_function_3() should be in a different class.

Comment: @MatsLindh, yes, this is what I was thinking. make this an answer for an upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a parent test class without the decorators - `TestParent` which contains the code from your `setUp` method, then inherit from this class in two subclasses - one that's decorated, and one that's not:

```
class TestClassParent(testcases.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # contains my setup that I want to use in all functions for this test class

@mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'class_fun_2')
@mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'class_fun_1')
class TestClassMocked(TestClassParent):
    def test_function_1(self, mocked_class_fun_1, mocked_class_fun_2):
        # I want to use those mocked functions here

    def test_function_2(self, mocked_class_fun_1, mocked_class_fun_2):
        # I want to use those mocked functions here too

class TestClassNotMocked(TestClassParent):
    def test_function_3(self):
        # I do not want to use those mocked functions here
```

That will allow you to share the setup code, and specify which methods shouldn't be mocked.

Comment: Ok, but better if the base class does not inherit from TestCase.